# install exact version of ppa package

Tags: package-management, upgrade, ppa

As I understand, to upgrade a ppa package, the following commands

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:user/ppa-name
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

will upgrade to the lastest version of the package. For example,

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:bluetooth/bluez
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

will upgrade the lastest version of bluez.

First question: this is stable lastest version or beta lastest version?

Second question: in the case I don't want the lastest version, I just want the version between my using version and the lastest version, what should I do? For example, my using version of bluez is 5.37, I want to upgrade to version 5.48 (not the lastest version).

Comment: Installation done using ppa depends solely on the owner of ppa that which version he is providing.like stable or beta. If there are multiple versions available you can use version, for eg. `sudo apt install package=version`

Comment: You mean use this command after two command  "sudo add-apt-repository ppa:user/ppa-name" and "sudo apt-get update" above

Comment: Yeah while installing the app.

Comment: Do I need remove installed version before do it.

Comment: You can try installing. It must replace the installed version automatically.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Install a specific version like this:

```
apt install packageName=versionName
```

for example:

```
apt install bluez=5.43-2+deb9u1
```

The owner of the ppa would have to say if it's stable or beta - like on the website where you found the ppa name and details.

Comment: you mean using "apt install packageName=versionName" after 2 commands "sudo add-apt-repository ppa:user/ppa-name" and  "sudo apt-get update"

Comment: You only have to install the ppa once ever on the machine. You run the update periodically to have a fresh list of the software versions in the ppa. Then you run install to install it (or upgrade to upgrade what you've already installed).

So the short answer is:

Don't need to re-install the ppa.
Then do run the upgrade.
Then run the install.

Comment: I run "sudo apt install bluez=5.48-0ubuntu3" but not success, it return "E: Version '5.48-0ubuntu3' for 'bluez' was not found". What happen? Following https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/bionic/+source/bluez, I guess "5.48-0ubuntu3" is correct name

Comment: Try running this to see what versions are available: apt-cache madison bluez

Comment: It just " 5.37-0ubuntu5.1 ". The command "sudo apt upgrade" installs newer versions of many packages , but I just want to upgrade things involve in bluez, how to do it?

Comment: apt upgrade bluez. It will also upgrade just the dependencies that bluez has.